# missing post on stackoverflow .htaccess tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tags

I just asked a question on SO and then a second later when I returned to the main page I couldn't find it.

I have repeatedly refreshed and searched the whole page using the search function of my browser and no signs of it. The funny thing is it **does** exist and I **can** find it in my profile.

Also the posts on SO at the moment go back at least 2hrs. Also this tag **.htaccess** isn't in my ignored tags.

I know the search is working becuase it is showing another .htaccess query from an hour ago.

Is this a bug you guys should know about? Or something wrong on my side?

[Question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569560/htaccess-syntax-error-when-shorting-urls)

---

What I am doing. Going to-> www.stackoverflow.com (main drop page) searching using cmd+F or crtl+F for .htaccess

Finding one post from an hour ago and nothing else related.

Wondering if this is the same for everyone.

Comment: The third question in the result is yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: @hims056 so it shows up there? How odd

Comment: From where were you seeing? I mean which tab? Newest? Active? Did you filter the tab?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, this is from the www.stackoverflow.com page, where I thought you saw all

Comment: Yea like in the link in the Meta question. I don't understand why I'm being voted down here, I'm only trying to highlight something that seems to be a problem on SO. I read other similar questions and this is relatively unique

Comment: @AdamBrown [Downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  So people could be disagreeing with idea that this is a bug.  Or it could be related to the question itself.  You are not describing the "bug" very well so it is very difficult for anyone to attempt to reproduce

Comment: @psubsee2003 thank you for the comment. I have described what I am doing hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 4):

There's no guarantee that your question will show up on your own main page.

Although the question is not in your ignored tags you don't mention that it's in your favourites. You have never answered a [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) before and this is the first time you've asked one.

I suspect the simple reason that it's not showing up on your main page is that there's no reason for it to do so. You don't even need the ability to search for it as it's in your profile.

As the question has definitely been posted, [and appears when you search for it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2062450+%5B.htaccess%5D) don't worry; it's showing on someone's front page.

Comment: Thank you for being civil and suggesting a possible answer. So this is how SO works? The thing is all other questions I have ever asked always show up here. I'm not so worried about someone not answering it, more so about their being an unidentified bug

Comment: Yes, it determines what questions you're most likely to want to see and displays them to you. If you click on the "Questions" tab rather than view your own main page I see it on page 11 (when the page-size is 50). By the time you read this it'll probably be on page 12.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So you don't see it on the mainpage either? I have just added .htaccess to my favourite tags and its still not showing up, just thought I'd add that.

Comment: No, my main page is all Python and SQL; with a bit of Java, PHP or C# being pulled in by those.